# What is the best way to Iterate through a Treeview Collection to update a Numbering Scheme?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I have a WPF `Treeview` control with an `ObservableCollection<TreeItemModel>` binded to its ItemsSource

This treeview can have the following structure to the n'th Level:

```
1
|-1.1
   |-1.1.1
   |-1.1.2
|-1.2
2
|-2.1
|-2.2
```

When an Item is re-arranged in this ObservableCollection, e.g 2.2 is moved under 1.1 to become 1.1.3.

How do i loop through this collection and update all of the numbers attached to each node?

Comment: See my solution at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57872110/how-to-sort-a-dictionary-for-treeview-output-by-character-for-character/57873428#comment102200097_57873428  Make TrrItemModel IComaparable and then use my CompareTo method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a view model with a recursive tree item structure, you may add a method that recursively updates all numbers:

```
public class TreeItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<TreeItem> Children { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<TreeItem>();

    private string number;

    public string Number
    {
        get { return number; }
        set
        {
            if (number != value)
            {
                number = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(
                    this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Number)));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < Children.Count; i++)
            {
                Children[i].Number = string.Format("{0}.{1}", number, i + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<TreeItem> TreeItems { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<TreeItem>();

    public void UpdateTreeItemNumbers()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < TreeItems.Count; i++)
        {
            TreeItems[i].Number = (i + 1).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever you call the `UpdateTreeItemNumbers()` method of the view model, all numbers will be regenerated.

---

For completeness, the TreeView XAML would look like this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TreeItems}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: So a couple of problems with this,  It works but does not seem to take into account more Levels than 2 (need n'th level)

When re-arranging the list via Drag Drop, Stackoverflows occur within the Number properties set Logic foreach loop.  Would you have any idea what might be the problem with this?

Comment: No idea, the code works fine for me with as many levels you like. Make sure you call the UpdateTreeItemNumbers method once after all rearranging has been done.

Comment: Yep, My apologies, Works perfectly now with your edits :) I implemented before i seen your latest edits, Thanks!  Alot more simple than i first imagined, I will accept as answer

Comment: Sorry one further comment, I am still getting Stack Overflows in the Number's Set Property - Specifically  Children[i].Number = string.Format("{0}.{1}", number, i + 1);

Comment: Maybe you have created loops in your tree structure, i.e. the Children collection of one TreeItem contains an element that at the same time is a parent or grandparent of the same TreeItem. You must of course make sure that this won't occur.

Comment: So yep,  My problem was my drag & drop functionality in the Treeview was copying and leaving the original Item, while making a duplicate at its new location.  thanks for your help Clemens!,  I have now fixed this.

Comment: Hi Clemens,  I know its been a while but I have one further question to ask with this if thats alright?  When fixing the sequence numbers using this functionality,  is it possible to set the Child's Parent?  E.g Each Step has an id, and each child step would have the Id of its parent?